# Why does "-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;" make some divs disappear?

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit, css-transforms

The following code should show a header bar, a footer bar, and an image, but for some reason, as soon as I add `.div1 { -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; }` I only get the header bar. I know it appears to have some unnecessary divs and style applied, but I do need them for effects that I have stripped out to make debugging easier. My page code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px;
            }
            .div1 {
                -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            }
            .div2 {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            img {
                max-width: 50%;
                max-height: 50%;
                display: block;
            }            
            .footer {
                position: fixed;
                bottom : 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="div1">
            <div class="div2">
                <div class="header">
                    Header
                </div>
                <div class="imgdiv">
                    <img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2012/5/18/1337331092888/Cwm-Idwal-Snowdonia.-Mich-007.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    Footer
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the problem here is similar to the well-known behavior where `position: absolute / fixed` div's that don't have a defined height / width can often disappear.  In your case, the 3d canvas is looking for `<div class="div1">` to have a width defined on it, otherwise it just floats aimlessly in space because you gave it properties that make use of the 3d canvas and I believe that in some indirect way causes it not to expand to contain the child divs.

In any case, you can see that defining `height` and `width` on the element with `preserve-3d` fixes the issue in the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nY9v6/

Comment: Sure thing! It's important to remember that the spec for these things is not yet final.  Even CSS3 animations (a spec that is more mature than 3d canvas) has been found buggy (because of the spec, not because of browser implementation) and the spec will change soon.

Comment: That's interesting, do you know of any articles that discuss the bugs in the spec?

Comment: No, but I chatted with a conference speaker about it Friday.  Not sure if you're aware of the issue with the inability to do CSS transitions/animations on `display: none`.  Jonathan Snook discusses it here: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/preparetransition-jquery-plugin ... anyway, they have decided the spec is flawed for making animation on `display: none` impossible and will be changing that soon.

Answer (score -3):

good sample

http://unformedbuilding.com/demo/2012/css-transforms/3d/3d-transform-style.html